# Adding an ArcSegment on a WPF Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, canvas

I'm trying to add to a WPF canvas a rounded corner rectangle. I read in several post ways to work with rectangles, but they are usually to add UI elements, using LineGeometry for example, not objects on WPF canvas.

Can someone help me with how to handle the ArcSegment class to have it added to a canvas in the same way I add a line?

For example when working with a line:

First I define the line parameters

```
Line botLine = new Line();
botLine.X1 = x + width - radius;
botLine.Y1 = y;
botLine.X2 = x + radius;
botLine.Y2 = y;
```

Then I can add the line to canvas like this:

```
canvas1.Children.Add(botLine);
```

But I cannot add an ArcSegment using the same method. What would be the approach in this case? Also there is a way to join the line and the arc together in a single entity?

Comment: You know there is a Rectangle class with RadiusX and RadiusY properties for its corner radii?

Comment: @Clemens Yes, I'm aware, but the radius is fixed and I cannot anchor the rectangle properly (or I couldn't find a way to anchor it).

Comment: You would set the attached properties `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top`.

Comment: @Clemens After your comment I read into it, but then for what I want it's better to have a custom path/geometry/figure that I can use a formula or another object references as an anchor point. Thank you for your comments, they were useful, but I found that the solution proposed below was just what I needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot add an `ArcSegment` to a `Canvas` because it is not a `Shape`; it is part of the geometry API and represents an arc in a piece of path-based geometry, but it is not a class you would typically use directly.

There is no `Shape` that corresponds directly to an 'arc', but you can create a `Path` with a single arc for its geometry.  The easiest way to do this in C# is by using `StreamingGeometry` for the path data:

```
var g = new StreamGeometry();

using (var gc = g.Open())
{
    gc.BeginFigure(
        startPoint: new Point(0, 0), 
        isFilled: false, 
        isClosed: false);

    gc.ArcTo(
        point: new Point(100, 100),
        size: new Size(100, 100),
        rotationAngle: 0d,
        isLargeArc: false,
        sweepDirection: SweepDirection.Clockwise,
        isStroked: true,
        isSmoothJoin: false);
}

var path = new Path
           {
               Stroke = Brushes.Black,
               StrokeThickness = 2,
               Data = g
           };

canvas1.Children.Add(path);
```

Adjust the parameters as necessary to fit your use case.  To see how to declare path geometry in XAML, see [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293(v=vs.110).aspx) on WPF's path markup syntax.

Comment: No problem!  Note that I recommend reading up on parameters like `isLargeArc` and `sweepDirection`, as you may need to change these values based on the size and direction of the arc.